# Create a Q and A for where to get resources

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Being that Im new to programming (yes, I know you've read that in a million of SO questions) I need resources to learn about all the different aspects of programming. Besides for myself I've seen alot of other SO users ask these type of questions, and then the question gets closed because it is not appropriate for the site.

While I can search over the web for the best resources, I find that I basicly look through a couple of websites listing "top 10" resources for learning XXXXX, and they aren't helpful because Im not really speaking to a person.

On SO though, I find everyone to be very helpful, and additionally you are speaking to a person who can address your specific taste, and request. Therefore I was wondering, wouldn't it be a good idea if there were to be created a seperate flow of Q and A's - much like this SO meta, that were to help people choose resources- meaning true and tried books, and documents for their topic they are interested in.

And although i mentioned earlier about this feature being for newbies - even experienced programmers need resources here and there to refresh themselves so I think it is applicable across the board.

I thought it was a good idea, and want to hear what others think of my idea.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md)

Comment: cant check out link at the moment will check later. Just to avoid mis-understanding, i was refering to books, documents ect. and not the actual code.

Comment: Implementing this would destroy the very reason this is always suggested; the experts would leave.  All newbies want something like this, and ask SO to implement it because this is where the experts are.  What they don't realize is that doing so would cause those same experts to leave, thereby removing the entire reason for the feature (and the site, too).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok. We will have a small demo of what will happen if *opinion based questions* like - *which site is the best for learning XXXXX* are allowed to linger around.

> OP : Which site is the best to learn language L?
>
> User -X -- > Go to site X. It has loads of examples and a whole list
>   of tutorials.
>
> User -Y --> Use site Y. It is awesome.
>
> User - IAmATroll --> Use.
>   www.someUselessSiteWhereTheTrollMakesSomeMoney.com . It contains
>   everything. Additionally it includes things like language C, Pill Z
>   and Clothes C. You can buy a house, a remote controlled car etc.
>
> OP - I still don't know which site is the best!
>
> ***** behind the scenes ******
>
> (Moderator M - Holy mother of God. I've gotto remove this question.)

Comment: That's a benign one. Too little spam, and generally too few "answers".

Comment: @Deduplicator - Agreed. I didn't have time to write about *wars based on opinions* :P

Comment: pretty funny way to explain it

Answer (score 6):

It's a fair request, but from past experience this is very unpopular with the community - mostly for the very same reasons why resource recommendations are off topic *here*: they're difficult to moderate, keep updated, and free from garbage.

So far, there has been no indication that Stack Exchange are thinking about building anything like it.

But you never know what the future will bring, of course.

In the meantime, [slant.co](http://slant.co) is trying to do something similar, for example.

Answer (score 5):

There is one place on SO where this sort of information may be provided, and that is the tag wiki. You can find this in several ways:

1. Hover over a tag on a question and press "info"
2. If viewing questions by tag, hit "learn more" at the top of the page
3. Go direct to /tags/foo/info, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info

While it's not the main purpose of the tag wiki, it's not unusual to see some lists of basic resources included. Since only high-rep (20k) users can directly edit them, there's less concern about spam/trolling. However, it does depend on someone being motivated to keep things up to date.