# Is it possible to salvage a closed off-topic question about resources?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, reopen-closed, community-wiki

From how I understand it, SO discourages questions about resources (books etc.) on learning how to program in a specific field or for a specific topic.

I asked [a particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50024380/what-are-your-recommended-resources-for-learning-extension-development-for-typo3) which specifically asks for resources because I believed it was important for the developers for this specific field, especially beginners.

**My reasons to ask this particular question:**

- Teach people to learn how to fish, not give them fish as "[Regex - don't feed them - teach them how to fish](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214238/regex-dont-feed-them-teach-them-how-to-fish)" brilliantly explains. I think it is better to give people answers that will show them how to help themselves rather than spoon-feed them specific answers to very specific questions they can then copy-paste, which solves their problem but often does not help them understand how things work under the hood.
- Some of the documentation in the specific field TYPO3 is outdated, because of very rapid development and deprecated features so it is not easy to find correct resources for your particular version right from the start. I was hoping to open up a question with answer(s) which could be kept up-to date in the future.

Unfortunately, my question was now closed. I am not sure how to proceed and if there is any chance of "rescuing" it.

**Example: Regex Q & A with resources as community wiki**

I now happened to come across a question + answer which provides [several resources for regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2444812). I absolutely **love** this and think it is very useful. Plus, I agree with the [rationale](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate) behind it.

Now I don't want to (mis)use someone else's idea and hop on the bandwagon but I do think this solution might also be useful in other tags [as others have already pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252869/2444812).

**I would like to know, what I can do about my question:**

- Specifically, I think my question should be **converted to community wiki** and I would like to provide an answer that is also community wiki (and will be kept up-to-date) but I don't see how I can do this now.

From how I understand it, creating a community wiki would solve the particular problem of competing, opiniated answers,  which was the reason for closing it: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as **they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam**"*

**And more generally:**

- If questions about resources are generally closed, how can people be helped to learn something?
- Or do they always have to ask very specific questions which is especially difficult at the beginning?
- Is SO just not the place for this?
- Or, **are any questions about resources for learning *not* discouraged and when does a question fit in that category?**

---

*Note: I realize similar questions have been asked here before and there is the help center. I have read quite a bit of these resources on meta but none of these have helped me (sufficiently) for my particular case.*

*Example: [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293601/2444812) explains some reasons for why it is not a good idea to ask for resources. Yes, maybe from the mod's POV because it might generate work. From the POV of someone trying to learn something and the POV of someone trying to help people to learn something, the given answers will most likely still be helpful. If the answer has a problem, it will most likely get a comment explaining the problem. This is based on the experience of what I have seen in the field. The answers I got for my question do not fall under this category of answers that should be discouraged in my opinion.*

Comment: related (possibly a duplicate): [Is the format of “The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List”-question sub-optimal?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354767/839601)

Comment: The usual problems of such questions already started to happen in your question: The author of answer 1 copied answer 2 and 3 into their answer making the other 2 useless. Also, I highly doubt the author of the first answer had the rights to upload the book-cover to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 8):

Community Wiki merely means that a post is a collaborative work of multiple people, rather than an individual person's post.  It doesn't just magically mean that the post no longer needs to follow the rules.

Opinionated questions will still result in people posting opinions, even if the post is CW, and requests for resources will still result in people posting spam, again, CW does nothing to stop that.  Having people editing said inappropriate content into a CW answer is no better than having them post it in their own answer.

Comment: From your answer I assume you are saying that *quesions asking about resources are bad questions for StackOverflow by default*. In that case there is really nothing I can do to salvage it and I would then prefer to delete my question and no longer ask such questions.